# Skipping one test if another failed

Tags: python-unittest

I'm writing some tests which rely on an external binary being present. Having a test case for ensuring `binary` is present and functioning seems useful. I want multiple tests, expressing:

- Is `binary` found by `subprocess.Popen`?
- Can it do basic X?
- Can it do basic Y?

I want a pattern to skip the basic tests `X` and `Y` if the first one fails. It would also be good to test several binaries in the same TestCase, with different kinds of `X` and `Y`.

Some approaches come to mind:

- Decorate `test_X()` and `test_Y()` with `@unittest.skipIf(basic failed)`, either through checking `TestResults` or setting a flag
- Have `test_basic()` call `TestResults.addSkip(test_binary_X)` upon failure (but this doesn't appear to be exposed)
- Put `test_basic()` into one `TestCase` and the others into another
- Make `test_basic()` part of `setUp()`, so it's run for each of `X` and `Y`

Unittest doesn't run tests in the order written, so it may be hard to ensure sequence.

```
# Something like:
class TestBasics(unittest.TestCase):
    test_basic(self):
        try:
            subprocess.Popen(["binary"], stdout=None, stderr=None)
        catch OsError as e:
            # fail depending on the error

    @unittest.skipIf( test binary in path failed )
    test_X(self):
        # assert

    @unittest.skipIf( test binary in path failed )
    test_Y(self):
        # assert
```

Comment: IMHO using the decorator would be the more Pythonic and elegant approach.

Comment: Right, but what kind of condition? Setting a flag in the class specifically for that test feels inelegant, and accessing the TestResults doesn't seem to be possible. Also, tests aren't guaranteed to run in the order written.

Comment: The tests run in parallel so you will have to synchronize them. I would suggest running them one by one in order. This may slow things down but you won't have to worry about race conditions.

Comment: Probably past relevance now but - the default unittest TestRunner does them in sequence, it's just alphabetical per TestCase (?) rather than the order of declaration. I might look into nose, perhaps it's better at linking tests together. Thanks!